# How do i check angular 8 application on safari 5.1.7 version

Tags: windows, browser, safari, angular8, polyfills

Are we able to test angular 8 application on safari browser 5.1.7 on windows OS or any polyfills to be added or any tools exists?

Comment: at least to me, it's totally unclear what your exact problem is... could you please elaborate? anyways, i typed "safari for windows"... maybe this helps you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68836/where-can-i-download-safari-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to be testing on Safari for Windows. It was discontinued in 2010 and is no longer supported by Apple.

According to [NetMarketShare](https://netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?options=%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22%24and%22%3A%5B%7B%22platform%22%3A%7B%22%24in%22%3A%5B%22Windows%22%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D%2C%22dateLabel%22%3A%22Trend%22%2C%22attributes%22%3A%22share%22%2C%22group%22%3A%22browser%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22share%22%3A-1%7D%2C%22id%22%3A%22browsersDesktop%22%2C%22dateInterval%22%3A%22Monthly%22%2C%22dateStart%22%3A%222019-06%22%2C%22dateEnd%22%3A%222020-05%22%2C%22pageLength%22%3A1000%2C%22segments%22%3A%22-1000%22%2C%22plotKeys%22%3A%5B%7B%22browser%22%3A%22Chrome%22%7D%2C%7B%22browser%22%3A%22Firefox%22%7D%2C%7B%22browser%22%3A%22Edge%22%7D%2C%7B%22browser%22%3A%22Internet%20Explorer%22%7D%2C%7B%22browser%22%3A%22QQ%22%7D%5D%7D), Safari for Windows has a 0.01% market share, less than QQ, Sogou, Opera, Yandex, UC, Maxthon, Baidu, Vivaldi, and Amigo. Unless you're also testing all of those, don't bother with Safari for Windows.

Safari for OSX or iOS is a different question, but to test those browsers, you'll need a device that is actually running OSX or iOS.